# how to store time.duration in protobuf3

Tags: go, time, duration, protobuf-3

in proto file...

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";

message aaaResponse{
  google.protobuf.Duration  min   = 2;
 }
```

...
will auto generate *duration.Duration

how to change the proto file to get time.Duration

Comment: try https://github.com/gogo/protobuf instead of google's protobuf library. There is an [extension](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/extensions.md) that converts duration.Duration to time.Duration.

Comment: What is unclear about the documentation? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/duration

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gogofaster

protoc --gogofaster_out=./ duration.proto
```